# Chrome Extension onMessage listener not receiving the second message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

I'm working on a private chrome extension which is designed to rake data from one tab, sanitize it, and populate the form data in another tab.

The logic flows like this:

1. The background script gets the tabids of the two tabs of interest and populates variables named feedId and targetId - background.js line 7ff
2. The Background script listens for the indication that the icon is clicked - background.js line 30
3. The background script sends a message to the content.js script to "Rake the Data." - background.js  line 38
4. The content.js receives the message and looks for the text "Rake the Data" then rakes the data and puts the data into an object - content.js line 17ff
5. The content.js sends a message back to the background script with an object of the data - content.js line 49
6. The background script receives the message with the object and then works to sanitize the data - background.js line 43ff
7. The background script then sends the sanitized data (I'm only sending one element at this stage of the script) to the targetId tab to begin the process of populating the fields by utilizing chrome.tabs.sendMessage - background.js line 73ff
8. I am expecting the message "Populate the Form" to show in the alert box in content.js line but it never gets alerted.

**What am I doing wrong in this last stage of the process?**

Here is my manifest.js:

```
{

    "manifest_version":
        2,

    "name":
        "Rake and Populate",

    "version":
        "0.3",

    "description" :
        "Rake data and populate a web form." ,

    "permissions" : [
            "tabs"
            ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
             ],

            "js": [
                "content.js"
                ]
            }
        ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
            ],
        "persistent": false
        },

    "icons" : {
        "16" : "rake16.png" ,
        "32" : "rake32.png" ,
        "48" : "rake48.png" ,
        "128" : "rake128.png"
    },

    "browser_action"    :   {
        "default_icon"  :   "rake16.png"
    }
}
```

Here is my background.js script:

```
// Let define some parameters for the query
// These are the websites we want to work with
var players = ["*://*.domain-one.com/*", "*://*.domain-two/add.html*"];
feedId = targetId = 0;

// query the tabs to get the Ids of the two tabs of interest
chrome.tabs.query({url: players}, mytabs);

// take the returned data from the query and find the ID for each
function mytabs(myinfo){

  var regex = /domain-one\.com/;

  if (myinfo[0].url.match(regex)){

      window.feedId = myinfo[0].id;
      window.targetId = myinfo[1].id;
      console.log('matched');
      console.log(window.feedId);
  } else {

      window.feedId = myinfo[1].id;
      window.targetId = myinfo[0].id;
  };
};


// let's listen for the button in the addres bar being clicked
// when the button is clicked, the function "iChooseToRake" will get executed
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(iChooseToRake);

// This function is called when the button is onClicked

function iChooseToRake(tab) { //the tab object is passed into the function

  //chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "Rake the Data");
  var rakeMessage = {message: "Rake the Data"};
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, rakeMessage);
}

// Set up a listener to receive the message from the rake
// saying "I have the data"
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(unsanitizedData, sender){

    // The data has been sent back in the object. Sanitize the data in the next few lines

        // Let's get the zip from the end of the full address
        // Check to see if there is a zip+4 code in the address

              var regex = /[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}/;  // does it match the pattern nnnnn-nnnn
              if (unsanitizedData.physical_address_full.match(regex)){
                var tempAddress = unsanitizedData.physical_address_full.match(regex)[0];  //populates tempAddress if matched

              } else {
                // We get here if the zip+4 matched failed.
                // Check to see if there is a match for a 5 digit zip
                var regex = /[0-9]{5}$/; //the pattern nnnnn at the end of the string
                var tempAddress = unsanitizedData.physical_address_full.match(regex)[0];   //populates tempAddress if matched
                  console.log('I matched the 5 digit zip pattern: ' +tempAddress);
              };

              //pack the sanitized data into an object
              var address = {
                  zip: tempAddress
                };

                sendNeededData(targetId, address);

  });

  // send the opject back to the correct tab
  function sendNeededData(targetId, address){

    // append the correct message in the object
    address.message = "Populate the Form";
    console.log(address);
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(targetId, address);

  };
```

Here is my content.js script:

```
// Function to Convert text to Initial Caps
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(function(word) {
    return (word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1));
  }).join(' ');
}


// The content script listens for a message from the background script
// which tells the browser to rake the data

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(messageRecieved);

function messageRecieved(txt, sender, sendResponse) {
  alert(txt.message);

  if (txt.message == "Rake the Data"){

    console.log('I was just told to rake the data');

    // Let's first read the data from the website
    var owner_name = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[6].innerText.trim(); // Owner Name
    owner_name = titleCase(owner_name); // Give it initial Caps

    var owner_address_full = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[7].innerText.trim();  // owner_full_address
    owner_address_full = titleCase(owner_address_full); // Give it initial Caps

    var physical_address_full = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[10].innerText.trim(); // Situs Address Content:
    physical_address_full = titleCase(physical_address_full); // Give it initial Caps

    var area_land = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[11].innerText.trim();  // Land Area: e.g. 11,260 Sq.Ft.
    var area_roof = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[7].innerText.trim();  // Gross Area: e.g. 2,709
    var area_air = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[8].innerText.trim();  // Living Area: e.g. 1,952

    // Now let's pack this data into an object and send it back to
    // the background script to be processed and fed to the form
    var parcelInfo = {
        owner_name: owner_name,
        owner_address_full: owner_address_full,
        physical_address_full: physical_address_full,
        area_land: area_land,
        area_roof: area_roof,
        area_air: area_air
      };

      console.log(parcelInfo);

      // send the message with the data packed into the object named "parcelInfo"
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(parcelInfo);
  };
};
```

Comment: 1) you're using a non-persistent background script which means your global variables disappear once the background page is suspended which can happen if you debug and pause the execution for more than 5 seconds. Store them in chrome.storage.local or in string-based localStorage 2) `alert` might be skipped in inactive tabs. 3) Use console.log or set a breakpoint in devtools debugger. 4) Also make sure the tab ids are correct in the background script by setting breakpoints in devtools debugger for the background page, and inspect the variables.

Comment: wOxxOm Thank you for the tips. 1.  I will explore using storage if I have trouble with the variables.  2.  I did not know that alerts might not fire on inactive tabs -- this might be the cause since the tab with the targetId is definitely not active. 4.  I have checked the tabIds -- they are written to console on background.js line 19.  So, I gather from your response that the problem is vanishing globals.  Do you have a ready dev reference to the life of such variables?

Comment: Solved! It turns out that the alert box directed to an inactive tab was being queued until I made the tab active by a simple mouse click on the title of the tab.  Essentially, the script execution was paused, waiting on the alert box closure; but since the message was directed to an inactive tab, the alert box was waiting for the tab to be active before it would appear.  Thanks for the heads up about inactive tabs and alert, w0xx0m.